# Unable to display remote images in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Carrier wave to upload images. But with the default store_dir in the image_uploader.rb file, it is appending the store_dir to my image path. So I am successful in displaying the images that I have uploaded. However, I have a database with remote image urls that are already existing. These remote image urls are not displayed, as it is appending the store_dir to the image path and they are not found.

For eg: 
It is taking "[http://myapp.com/images/I/51oYEfb%2B0WL.*SL160*.jpg](http://myapp.com/images/I/51oYEfb%2B0WL._SL160_.jpg)" as "**/uploads/product/productimage/1/http%3A/myapp.com/images/I/51oYEfb%252B0WL.*SL160*.jpg**"

Here is my code:

_product.html.erb

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <li> 
    <%= image_tag(product.productimage_url) if product.productimage? %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :productimage, ProductimageUploader
end
```

productimage_uploader.rb

```
class ProductimageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

I even tried nil as below and it still appends / to the image url:

```
def store_dir
  nil
end
```

Comment: I don't have code for this, but it seems that your issue is that Carrierwave is unable to determine whether a url is local or remote. If local, it loads okay (remember, the images in your system are stored somewhere) - the remote has to be denoted somehow.

Comment: Yes, I have used another column for remote_url as @ihaztehcodez has specified in the below answer. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you must have loaded the remote urls into your `products`' table's `productimage` column.

Perhaps the simplest way to accomplish your goal would to be add something like a `remote_url` column to the products table and not put remote URLs in the `productimage` column.  Then you could do something like:

```
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def image_url
    productimage.present? ? productimage_url : remote_url
  end
end
```

Then change your view to:

```
<%= image_tag(product.image_url) if product.image_url.present? %>
```

If your `products` table is already populated with remote urls from your app previously using something other than carrierwave, another option that might be better would be to write a rake task to download and re-save them with carrierwave.  That might look something like:

```
Product.all.each do |product|
  temp_location = Rails.root.join('tmp', File.basename(product.attributes['productimage']))
  uri = URI(product.attributes['productimage'])

  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri

    http.request request do |response|
      File.open(temp_location, 'w') do |file|
        response.read_body do |chunk|
          file.write chunk
        end
      end
    end
  end

  product.productimage = File.open(temp_location)
  product.save!

  File.unlink(temp_location)
end
```

Comment: I have added a remote_url column to my table and it worked fine for me. Thanks. But I have a question, is there a way to extract the http url from "/uploads/product/productimage/1/http%3A/myapp.com/images/I/51oYEfb%252B0WL.SL160.jpg" by using a slice operation on the string? I mean if it has http in the string slice it else use the original url. I tried it but it didn't work.  Can we do that or is it not possible? @ihaztehcodez

Comment: @suma-chaganti You _could_ use a regex for that (`/(http.*$)/` then the remote url lives in `$1`), but that is a bit hacky and would break if a user uploads a file with 'http' in the filename.